# Запустить java файл с кастомной версией java

Tags: java, linux, jar

Добрый день.
У меня имеется некий сервер на Debian на котором я запускаю некие Java файлы. Для их запуска используется Java, которая уже установлена в систему.
Собственно вопрос в том, а могу ли я скачать другую версию Java в какую-то папку и уже запускать мои файлы не с помощью системной версии Java, а с той, которую скачали отдельно? Если да - то какой командой. Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, разумеется можете.
Допустим, вы запускаете файл с помощью системной java так:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

тогда если скачав другую версию, например в директорию `/home/user/downloads/jdk/` вы можете запускать свой файл так:

```
/home/user/downloads/jdk/bin/java -jar myapp.jar
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако теперь возникает ошибка "Отказано в доступе". И ничего подробнее не написано

Comment: Вероятно, что-то не так с настройкой прав.

Comment: Да, была ошибка, но не с правами. Неправильно был распакован архив, сейчас все работает штатно, спасибо вам